# How to create a workout station on Pandora?

Tags: pandora

I know Pandora now has the ability to create *genre* stations, but I'd like to create a station with a decent variety of up temp songs for working out. The only option I can think of is to curate a station until its shaped into a format good for working out, but I am hoping for an out of the box solution.

So other than spending time to curate a station is there a way to create a workout station?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandora doesn't offer the option of creating custom stations by genres but it has an [extensive list of curated genre stations](http://www.pandora.com/#!/genres/), which includes just over a [dozen of workout stations](http://www.pandora.com/#!/genres/workout) in different styles.

Comment: Excellent the curated [workout stations](http://www.pandora.com/#!/genres/workout) will definitely get me started.